# User type and user Id is NULL in Laravel Auditing table

Tags: php, laravel, auditing, laravel-auditing

I use Laravel auditing for tracking model changes in my system. I see the **admin** type track user type and Id but for staff users, user_type and user_id is **NULL** and here is my code:

***config/audit.php***

```
<?php

return [

    'enabled' => env('AUDITING_ENABLED', true),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Audit Implementation
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Define which Audit model implementation should be used.
    |
    */

    'implementation' => OwenIt\Auditing\Models\Audit::class,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Morph prefix & Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Define the morph prefix and authentication guards for the User resolver.
    |
    */

    'user' => [
        'morph_prefix' => 'user',
        'guards'       => [
            'admin',
            'api',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Audit Resolvers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Define the User, IP Address, User Agent and URL resolver implementations.
    |
    */
    'resolver' => [
        'user'       => OwenIt\Auditing\Resolvers\UserResolver::class,
        'ip_address' => OwenIt\Auditing\Resolvers\IpAddressResolver::class,
        'user_agent' => OwenIt\Auditing\Resolvers\UserAgentResolver::class,
        'url'        => OwenIt\Auditing\Resolvers\UrlResolver::class,
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Audit Events
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The Eloquent events that trigger an Audit.
    |
    */

    'events' => [
        'created',
        'updated',
        'deleted',
        'restored',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Strict Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Enable the strict mode when auditing?
    |
    */

    'strict' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Audit Timestamps
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Should the created_at, updated_at and deleted_at timestamps be audited?
    |
    */

    'timestamps' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Audit Threshold
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify a threshold for the amount of Audit records a model can have.
    | Zero means no limit.
    |
    */

    'threshold' => 0,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Audit Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The default audit driver used to keep track of changes.
    |
    */

    'driver' => 'database',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Audit Driver Configurations
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Available audit drivers and respective configurations.
    |
    */

    'drivers' => [
        'database' => [
            'table'      => 'audits',
            'connection' => null,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Audit Console
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Whether console events should be audited (eg. php artisan db:seed).
    |
    */

    'console' => false,
];
```

***Staff model***

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Notifications\StaffsResetPasswordNotification;
use OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\Auditable;

class Staff extends Authenticatable implements Auditable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use \OwenIt\Auditing\Auditable;
    protected $guard = 'staff';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','type'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new StaffsResetPasswordNotification($token));
    }
}
```

here is what I see in the database table:

[image: i]

I know there must be some easy way to handle the issue but not sure how.
Thanks

Comment: Use `Log::info(Auth::user()->id)` to see if the user is even being recognized as logged in before said insertion code runs.

Comment: Yes, it works to see user id but not saving it in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an easy way to handle this, actually, the answer I found in [GitHub](https://github.com/owen-it/laravel-auditing/issues/528#issuecomment-519549426) for this problem was to create a new custom resolver and change the resolver class from the ***config/audit.php***. that was the working but the easier way just pass all the guard/user types you want to audit into the guard's array in the ***config/audit.php*** in the **User Morph prefix & Guards section**.
like this:

```
'user' => [
        'morph_prefix' => 'user',
        'guards'       => [
            'admin',
            'staff',
            'student',
            'api',
        ],
    ],
```

the other way was to customize resolver like this:

"override" the UserResolver class.

In config/audit.php:

```
...
    'resolver' = [
        // ...
        'user' => App\Resolvers\UserResolver::class,
        // ...
    ],
...
```

In app/Resolvers/UserResolver.php:

```
  /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function resolve()
    {
        $guards = config('audit.user.guards'); // I only removed the default array value
        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return Auth::guard($guard)->user();
            }
        }
    }
```